# gcd of list of floats - incorrect output from fractions

Tags: python, list, floating-point, greatest-common-divisor

I need a function that gets a list of floats, and calculates the gcd of that list.

For instance, given the input `[1/2.0, 1/3.0]` I expect the output to be `1/6.0`

However it's not. it prints `5.55111512313e-17` or in other words, zero. This is my code:

```
def gcd(L):
    return reduce(fractions.gcd, L)

print gcd([1/2.0, 1/3.0])
```

What's wrong here? Is there any way I can fix it?

Comment: The closest IEEE 754 64-bit binary float to 1/3.0 is 0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125. You may need to supply the inputs as Fraction instances that can exactly represent 1/3.0,  without first going through float.

Comment: @SergeBallesta It is well defined, as the largest number that is a factor of all the inputs. It is just not what the OP needs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Fraction` objects, because `float` is imprecise, that is why the `Fraction` class exists:

```
>>> reduce(fractions.gcd, [Fraction(1,2), Fraction(1,3)])
Fraction(1, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid going through the floating point hassle, simply keep your numbers as fractions preserving their accuracy:

```
import fractions

def gcd(L):
    return reduce(fractions.gcd, map(fractions.Fraction, L))

print gcd(['1/2', '1/3'])
# 1/6
```

Comment: I can't use strings as I don't know the real values that will appear in the list in advance.

Comment: Well then build a `Fraction` object directly from the input if you can

Answer (score 0):

"Just use fractions or decimals" doesn't help if your program has to deal with float inputs.

I've done the following using numpy for my usecase:

```
def is_mostly_integer(value, epsilon=0.001):
    """
    Tests whether a float value is close to an integer
    Can be applied to numpy arrays
    """
    return numpy.abs(value - value.round()) < epsilon

def float_gcd(float_array, max_trials=100):
    """
    Find the greatest common denominator of a set of float values.
    Assumes that the set of floats was generated by multiplying integers with a float constant.
    """
    numpy_array = numpy.array(float_array)
    sorted_values = numpy.unique(numpy_array)
    sorted_values.sort()
    differences = numpy.diff(sorted_values)
    first_guess = min(differences)
    divisor = next(div for div in range(1, max_trials) if
         is_mostly_integer(sorted_values/first_guess*div).all())
    gcd = first_guess / divisor
    return gcd

for i in range(10000):
    int_arr = numpy.random.randint(-50, 50, (100,))
    factor = numpy.random.randn(1)
    gcd = float_gcd(int_arr * factor)
    assert(is_mostly_integer(gcd/factor))
```